# Referencing a Terraform map output

Tags: for-loop, terraform, output

I'm using the following code to create a map output from a module that is creating Azure VMs using a for_each loop.

```
output "vm_ids" {
  description = "Virtual machine IDs"
  value = tomap({
    for k, server in azurerm_windows_virtual_machine.vm : k => server.id
  })
}
```

I can't figure out how to reference individual entries in the map correctly. If I output the whole map `module.vm_ADDS01.vm_ids` (vm_ADDS01 is the module identifier) I get the following.

```
  + testvmid = {
      + "app_01" = (known after apply)
      + "app_02" = (known after apply)
    }
```

I've tried the below variations providing the key of one of the entries,

```
module.vm_ADDS01.vm_ids[app_01]
module.vm_ADDS01.vm_ids[app_01].id
module.vm_ADDS01[app_01].vm_ids
```

I receive the following error.

> A reference to a resource type must be followed by at least one attribute access, specifying the resource name.

Comment: What is `testvmid`? Where does it come from?

Comment: It looks like this may be a typo of not designating `app_01` as a string with `"` syntax. Try that and see if it fixes your issue.

Comment: Marcin testvmid was just a temporary output I setup in my root code to test referencing one of the module outputs.

@MattSchuchard Thankyou that was the issue so the working code is
module.vm_ADDS01.vm_ids["app_01"]

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Matt for pointing out the missing quotes. The map key needed to be provided in quotes so the working example is.

```
module.vm_ADDS01.vm_ids["app_01"]
```